# Demotion/Promotion Script

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I wrote a code which is creating a Session and write an the Session Arrays diffrent things like: Username and Rank.

I wrote then a function which is checking the Visited Profile Name and Rank and the Own Name and Rank to be sure that you have enough power to Promote/Demote.

I want to know if there is a smarter version or if this is the best version I can wrote.

I want to say that I am a newbie in PHP.

The code workes fine btw. I just want ideas and suggestions for improve my code.

Demote/Promote Button Script:

```
<?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['besucht']) && $_SESSION['besucht'] == 1) {
            if (!empty($own_username) && $_SESSION['user-permissions']-1 == 6 || $_SESSION['user-permissions']-1 == 7) {
                if ($_SESSION['visit_user-permissions']-1 < 6 && $_SESSION['visit_user-permissions']-1 !=  $_SESSION['user-permissions']-1) {
                    echo('
                    <form action="./tools/php/demoter_promoter/index.php" method="POST">
                        <table style="width: 100%;">
                            <tr style="width: 100%;">
                                <td style="width: 50%;">
                                ');
                                if($visit_permissions-1 > 0) {
                                    echo('
                                    <button style="float: left;" title="Den Rank um 1 Degradieren" id="demoter" name="demoter" value="'.$visit_username.'">
                                        Demote
                                    </button>
                                    ');
                                }
                                echo('
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 50%;">
                                ');
                                if($visit_permissions-1 < 5) {
                                    echo('
                                    <button style="float: right;" title="Den Rank um 1 Befördern" id="promoter" name="promoter" value="'.$visit_username.'">
                                        Promote
                                    </button>
                                    ');
                                }
                                echo('
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                    ');
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Promote Function:

```
<?php
    FUNCTION promote($user) {
        require('../connector/connector.php');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` = ?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();
        $obj = $result->fetch_array();
        $permissions = $obj['permissions'];
        if ($permissions < 5) {
            $query = "UPDATE `members` SET `permissions` = ? WHERE `username` = '".$user."';";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $permissions = $permissions + 1;
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $permissions);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            back_to_home($db);
        }
        else {
            back_to_home($db);
        }
    }
?>
```

The `$user` variable is seted by the `$_SESSION['visit_user-username']`

Demote Function:

```
<?php
    FUNCTION demote($user) {
        require('../connector/connector.php');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` = ?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();
        $obj = $result->fetch_array();
        $permissions = $obj['permissions'];
        if ($permissions != 0 && $permissions < 6) {
            $query = "UPDATE `members` SET `permissions` = ? WHERE `username` = '".$user."';";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $permissions = $permissions - 1;
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $permissions);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            back_to_home($db);
        }
        else {
            back_to_home($db);
        }
    }
?>
```

The `back_to_home`function is a simple function which is unset all `$_SESSION['visit_user-*']` and send back to the stard page.

---EDITS---

This is the function caller I wrote:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['promoter'])) {
        $user = "";
        $user = $_POST['promoter'];
        promote($user);
    }
    else {
        if(isset($_POST['demoter'])) {
            $user = "";
            $user = $_POST['demoter'];
            demote($user);
        }
        else {
            header('Location: ../../../');
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

This is the User Page Loader Function I wrote:

```
<?php
    $value = "";
    $value = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if(isset($_SESSION['user-username']) && $value == "?logout") {
        require('./tools/php/pageloader/pages/logout.php');
    }
    else {
        $search  = '?';
        $replace = '';
        $subject = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $new_value = str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` = ?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $new_value);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();
        $obj = $result->fetch_array();
        if ($obj['username'] != null && $obj['username'] == $new_value) {
            $_SESSION['visit_user-username'] = $obj['username'];
            $_SESSION['visit_user-e_mail'] = $obj['e_mail'];
            $_SESSION['visit_user-register_date'] = $obj['register_date'];
            $_SESSION['visit_user-last_login_date'] = $obj['last_login_date'];
            $_SESSION['visit_user-steam_id'] = $obj['steam_id'];
            $_SESSION['visit_user-permissions'] = $obj['permissions'] + 1;
            $_SESSION['visit_user-ban_status'] = $obj['banned'] + 1;
            require('./tools/php/pageloader/pages/usercheck.php');
        }
        else {
            //echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=./'>");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['user-permissions']-1 == 6` there is something strange and probably wrong with your code design

Comment: you mean the -1 or? yea xD I need to do -1 because I wrote the Permissions with +1 in the Array xD 6 is for Admins and 7 for Owners. Or what did you mean directly?

Comment: User should also be parametized.

Comment: @Dharman which one do you mean? the visitor or the visited? In the parameter I only put the visited because I want to call him, that happens in another function (See edit section in my post), or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I meant `WHERE username = '".$user."';`

Comment: I change it from ```$query = "UPDATE `members` SET `permissions` = ? WHERE `username` = '".$user."';``` to ```$query = "UPDATE `members` SET `permissions` = ? WHERE `username` = ?;";``` and changed ```$stmt->bind_param('s', $permissions);``` to ```$stmt->bind_param('ss', $permissions, $user);```

Comment: Is there anything else on this code where I can improve?